# How to retrieve the text inside the objects of array?

Tags: html, arrays, extjs, sencha-touch

i have an array of this format:

```
points.push(
{text: '<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;">hi</span>'},
{text: '<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;">hello</span>'},
{text: '<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;">call</span>'},
{text: '<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;">crow</span>'});
```

when i use `alert(points[1]);` i get `[object object]` obviously because there are some html code around it...

can anyone tell me how to retrieve the text inside this array.
i need the output as only "hi" or "hello" or "call" or "crow"

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the proper syntax would be `points[1].text`

It is not because there is html code, javascript isn't looking at the contents.  For each pushed element you are using a javascript object literal `{ property : "value" }` meaning for each object you pushed.  You would have to reference the property you instantiated, by assigning it a value, in dot notation `object.property`. if you want to not use json, change your push statement like so.

```
points.push(
'<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;">hi</span>',
'<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;">hello</span>',
'<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;">call</span>',
'<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;">crow</span>');
```

If you use this type of syntax, (without json `{}`) you will simply have an array of strings that you could referance like you originally intended.

Also, understand that it does not care what is contained in these string values, it treats them just like any other string.

Answer (score 0):

`alert(points[1].text)` will give you the text: `'<span style="font-weight: bold;font-size:25px;">hi</span>'` for example. You will have to extract the proper content after that.